# How to insert references in horizontal mode?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, vertical, horizontal

I am defining an exercise environment as follows:

```
\newtheorem{aufg}{Exercise}
\newenvironment{aufgabe}[2] % #1: Anzahl der Punkte, #2: Anzahl der Karozeilen unter der Aufgabenstellung
{\setcounter{karo_counter}{#2}
 \begin{aufg} (#1 Points)\\[0.5em]}
{\end{aufg}
 \karos{\arabic{karo_counter}}
 \newpage
 \phantom{.}\hfill Name: \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \\
 \karos{43}
 \begin{flushright}
  \underline{\hspace*{2.5cm}} \\ (#1 points)
  \end{flushright}
}
```

Unfortunately, when calling it via

```
\begin{aufgabe}{3+3=6}{40}
    XXX
\end{aufgabe}
```

I run into `` You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. \endaufgabe ...underline {\hspace *{2.5cm}} \\ (## ``.
This is caused by the `(#1 points)`in the third last line, if I remove that part it will work fine again. But I want to have that. How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: your error is `(#1 points)` the end-code has no arguments, only the begin code you need to save it in a command in the begin code and use at the end

Comment: you are right! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment by David Carlisle, the following code solves the issue:

```
\newtheorem{aufg}{Exercise}
\newenvironment{aufgabe}[2] % #1: Anzahl der Punkte, #2: Anzahl der Karozeilen unter der Aufgabenstellung
{\setcounter{karo_counter}{#2}
  \newcommand{\scoreawarding}{
    \begin{flushright}
      \underline{\hspace*{2.5cm}} \\ (#1 points)
    \end{flushright}
  }
 \begin{aufg} (#1 Points)\\[0.5em]}
{\end{aufg}
 \karos{\arabic{karo_counter}}
 \newpage
 \phantom{.}\hfill Name: \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots \\
 \karos{43}
 \scoreawarding
}
```